# Solubility Data

Tags: thermodynamics, chemical-engineering

I am trying to obtain solubility data for a polymer in sc-CO2 and the data is reported at each T and P as $$w \ \ \times \ 10^6$$ Does anyone know what this means?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like w is the inverse of parts per million ie if w = 1 the solubility is 1 part per million